# Graph and manipulate DSolve result

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, expression-manipulation

Given a `DSolve` example:

```
sol = Flatten[
DSolve[{D[x[t, th], {t, 2}] == -0.2*D[x[t, th], t]/2.30, 
 Derivative[1, 0][x][0, th] == 10.8*Cos[th], x[0, th] == 0}, 
x[t, th], t]]
```

Then assigning `sol` to a function:

```
 x[t,th]/.sol[[1]]
```

I'm having trouble plotting a 2D portion of it:

```
Plot[x[t,1],{t,0,20}]
```

And also trouble Manipulating it:

```
Manipulate[x[t,th], {th, 0, Pi/2}]
```

What mistakes am I making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think `x[t,th]/.sol[[1]]` does. From your question, Here is what I think you're trying to accomplish.

```
sol = Flatten[  DSolve[{D[x[t, th], {t, 2}] == -0.2*D[x[t, th], t]/2.30, 
    Derivative[1, 0][x][0, th] == 10.8*Cos[th], x[0, th] == 0}, 
   x[t, th], t]];

x[t_, th_] = sol[[1, 2]]; (* This defines the function using the solution from DSolve *)
```

To get the Plot do the following:

```
Plot[x[t, 1], {t, 0, 20}]
```

To Manipulate, do the following:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x[t, th], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 130}}], {th, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @RunnyKine. I'm taking a look now.

Comment: I edited your code so that the manipulate shows how the function transforms (added a constant range: `PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 130}}`. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @gpap. Thanks for the edit. Looks good.